# Name activation for my assistant. How could I create a function to execute a block of code when one name as input is said?

Tags: python-3.x, function, speech-recognition

I have been working on a virtual assistant project and wanted a voice activation system so that it isn't always listening to what I am saying unless I say its name.

This is the code for the speech recognition. and I am trying to create a function so that when my voice inputs "name" of the assistant, it activates. Once it does what I ask it once, it should go back to sleep unless I summon again.

```
def takeCommand():
    r = sr.Recognizer()

    with sr.Microphone() as source:

        print("Listening...")
        r.pause_threshold = 1
        audio = r.listen(source)

    try:
        print("Recognizing...")
        query = r.recognize_google(audio, language='en-us')
        print("User said: {query}\n")


    except Exception as e:
        (My exception handler. I did this to minimize the code)

    return query

if __name__ == '__main__':
    clear = lambda: os.system('cls')

    # This Function will clean any
    # command before execution of this python file
    clear()
    wishMe()
    usrname()
    voice_activation()

    while True:

        query = takeCommand().lower()

        # All the commands said by user will be
        # stored here in 'query' and will be
        # converted to lower case for easily
        # recognition of command
```

And after that, there are a list of commands like for example...

```
    elif 'open youtube' in query:
        (Assistant speaks)
        webbrowser.open("youtube.com")
```

I have tried making a new function like

```
def voice_activation
```

but I didn't know where to put it and how to structure it

There was a suggestion to create a class variable but I don't exactly know where I could place it in my program because of how its structured. Again, thank you for helping me with this program.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC-BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted and subsequent attempts will get you banned. If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323395/584192)?

Comment: All your questions should be answered at the link I pasted https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255583. If you have any follow-up questions, please ask on [meta].

Comment: Please read section "Why am I getting this message?" in the linked post.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of making a bunch of standalone functions, make them class methods instead. Then you can make a class variable voice_activated = False. Make a class method voice_activation like you said, then in that, an if statement. If 'assistant name' in query, voice activated = true. Then in all of your query functions you could encompass them in if voice activated= True, or something to that effect?